# Multiple GROUP_CONCATs in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE instructions (
 `id_instruction` INT(11),
 `id_step` INT(11)
);

CREATE TABLE steps (
 `id_instruction` INT(11),
 `id_step` INT(11),
 `val` VARCHAR(255)
);
```

One table contains instructions, another table contains steps. Each instruction may have many steps. Now, the data is:

```
INSERT INTO instructions (`id_instruction`, `id_step`) VALUES (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2);
INSERT INTO steps (`id_instruction`, `id_step`, `val` ) VALUES (1, 0, 'One'), (1, 0, 'Two'), (1, 0, 'Three'); /* step 0 */
INSERT INTO steps (`id_instruction`, `id_step`, `val` ) VALUES (1, 1, 'Five'), (1, 1, 'Six'), (1, 1, 'Seven'); /* step 1 */
INSERT INTO steps (`id_instruction`, `id_step`, `val` ) VALUES (1, 2, 'Eight'), (1, 2, 'Nine'), (1, 2, 'Ten'); /* step 2 */
```

For each instruction I want to have two concatenations - one which concatenates values from `val` column for the zero step, and another one which concatenates values from the same column for the largest step of the instruction. I know how to get the largest step and how to make a single group concatenation, but trying to do two concatenations, I get duplicates. Now, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT maxstep, i.id_instruction, i.id_step, GROUP_CONCAT(s.val) AS val_0 
FROM instructions i
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT MAX(id_step) AS maxstep, id_instruction  FROM instructions i
 GROUP BY i.id_instruction  
) i2 ON i2.id_instruction = i.id_instruction 
LEFT JOIN steps s ON s.id_instruction = i.id_instruction AND s.id_step = i.id_step 
GROUP BY i.id_instruction, i.id_step
```

It just concatenates values per a pair instruction-step. But I want to have one more concatenation which would also concatenate values for the `maxstep`. The desired result should look like this:

```
| maxstep | id_instruction |      val_0     |      val_1       |
|    2    |       1        | One,Two, Three | Eight, Nine, Ten |
```

PS. I do join instead of just MAX and grouping, because I want to use its value in additional joining for further concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called pivoting. In MySQL there's no built-in function for this, but you can do it like this:

```
SELECT maxstep, id_instruction, 
MAX(CASE id_step WHEN 0 THEN val END) AS val_0,
MAX(CASE id_step WHEN 1 THEN val END) AS val_1,
MAX(CASE id_step WHEN 2 THEN val END) AS val_2
FROM (
SELECT maxstep, i.id_instruction, i.id_step, GROUP_CONCAT(s.val) AS val
FROM instructions i
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT MAX(id_step) AS maxstep, id_instruction  FROM instructions i
 GROUP BY i.id_instruction  
) i2 ON i2.id_instruction = i.id_instruction 
LEFT JOIN steps s ON s.id_instruction = i.id_instruction AND s.id_step = i.id_step 
GROUP BY i.id_instruction, i.id_step
) sq
GROUP BY maxstep, id_instruction
```

Result:

```
maxstep id_instruction  val_0           val_1           val_2
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2           1           One,Two,Three   Five,Six,Seven  Ten,Eight,Nine
```

Comment: It works for this very data. However, I do not know maxstep beforehand. So, your query will not work, if maxstep is 3 or more.

Comment: Changed CASE id_step WHEN 2 to CASE id_step WHEN maxstep and now it works as expected. Thanks a lot, sir!

Comment: May you explain a little bit the sense of " MAX(CASE ... " statement. I know what MAX does and know the syntax of CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END? But their combination in your query looks rather strange for me, though it works great!

Answer (score 1):

By changing the query a little so that the inner join only gets the highest step and by setting the outer query to only take id_step=0 you can get what you want.

```
SELECT maxstep, i.id_instruction,GROUP_CONCAT(s.val) AS val_0, val_1 
FROM instructions i
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT MAX(ins.id_step) AS maxstep, ins.id_instruction, GROUP_CONCAT(st.val) as val_1 FROM instructions ins
 LEFT JOIN steps st ON st.id_instruction = ins.id_instruction AND st.id_step = ins.id_step 
 where (ins.id_instruction, ins.id_step) in (select id_instruction, max(id_step) from instructions group by id_instruction)
 GROUP BY ins.id_instruction, ins.id_step  
 order by maxstep, ins.id_instruction, st.val
) 
i2 ON i2.id_instruction = i.id_instruction 
LEFT JOIN steps s ON s.id_instruction = i.id_instruction AND s.id_step = i.id_step 
where i.id_step=0
GROUP BY i.id_instruction, i.id_step;
```

Result from the query with extended data now looks like

```
| maxstep | id_instruction |      val_0     |      val_1       |
|    2    |       1        |  One,Two,Three |  Eight,Nine,Ten  |
|    3    |       2        |  One,Two,Three |     21,22,23     |
```

Comment: I inserted additional data for the second instruction with three steps and found out that your query does not work as expected. I guess this is because of a subquery inside the join statement.

Comment: Did you refer to the fact that the values of the added steps didn't show up in the right order? I changed the inner GROUP_CONCAT to sort these values. I know you've already found a working example, but I was more curious if I could solve it this way.

Comment: If I have a second instruction with steps (0,1,2), the query returns only one row with NULL as val_1. If a second instruction has one more step, I get correct result but just for this very instruction, I mean, I get only one row, instead of two rows for the first and second instruction. But, I'm also curious if there is another way of doing this. Though, I expect that another query will not be so optimized-looking as the current working query.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I changed the inner join to take that into consideration and I now get two separate rows. It's the inner `where` line that I changed.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you then you can just ignore my final changes. I was just trying to figure out something different that worked, but you already have a working solution so I understand you might not be so interested in that :-)

Comment: Still, plus one for curiosity!

Comment: Thanks! Curiosity killed the cat...but still it pushes us forward :)